# Downloading dependencies from additional repository maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I want to use new version of Spring Boot in my webapp (1.4.0 RC1), so I added additional repository to my pom.xml file:

```xml
<project>
    <groupId>com.exampleRestApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And it works well with Idea, but when I'm trying to build the project with maven I'm getting this error:

```
   Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RC1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.4.0.RC1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Did you get this working? I am having the same problem... the Spring milestones repository is defined but it is not using it. It keeps trying on repo.maven.apache.org.

Answer (score 2):

Maven uses separate repository configuration for plugins and for "normal" dependencies. This means that you also need to add a `<pluginRepository>` to access the 1.4.0.RC1 version of Boot's Maven plugin:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the repository definition like:

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this repo

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
</repository>
```